# Merge 2 fields and insert into table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

hi i am trying to insert value into my output table 
in my Input table have

> profit  extra
>
> 10         20

when i insert into my output table it should get concatenated as

> cost
>
> 1020

```
sub test() 
Dim db As DAO.Database 
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset 
Set db = CurrentDb 
db. execut "Insert into OUTPUT_TBL (DESCRIPTION,COST,DEBIT,CREDIT) " & _
           " SELECT INPUT.DESCRIPTION,((INPUT.PROFIT)+(INPUT.EXTRA)) AS COST," & _
           "        IIF(EXTERNAL.SOLUTION='DEBIT',(AMOUNT),0) as DEBIT, " & _
           "        IIF(EXTERNAL.SOLUTION='CREDIT',(AMOUNT),0) AS CREDIT " & _
           "   FROM INPUT , EXTERNAL"
db.close 
end test
```

when i try to run it i am getting error as  run time error 3075

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues - noticed a typo, it should be db.execute "" not db.execut
Also, for string concatenation use & in Access SQL.  3075 means you used a bad operator.
Another thing, You may also need to add a JOIN to the SQL.

For example, to get you on the right track:

```
db.execute "Insert into OUTPUT_TBL (DESCRIPTION,COST,DEBIT,CREDIT) SELECT INPUT.DESCRIPTION,((INPUT.PROFIT)&""&(INPUT.EXTRA)) AS COST,IIF(EXTERNAL.SOLUTION='DEBIT',(AMOUNT),0) as DEBIT,  IIF(EXTERNAL.SOLUTION='CREDIT',(AMOUNT),0) AS CREDIT from INPUT JOIN EXTERNAL ON INPUT.KEY=EXTERNAL.KEY"
```

Comment: i have used the join but same issue is existing when i try to concatenate it, when i remove ((INPUT.PROFIT)&""&(INPUT.EXTRA)) AS COST the problem does not exit!! how can i over come this?

Comment: What happens when you try (CSTR(INPUT.PROFIT)&""&CSTR(INPUT.EXTRA)) ?  It may be a type conversion issue

Comment: it is working (INPUT.PROFIT & INPUT.EXTRA) found the answer in here http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/concat.php

Comment: Yeah, I thought the null string " " wasn't needed, but to my knowledge, it still should've concatenated if they are both string typed.